# Url Rewriting with .htaccess and 404 original path

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

I have a file test.php to rewrite in test.json

In .htaccess i set
`RewriteRule ^test.json$ /test.php`

The rewrite work correctly, but if i open the old url, test.php,
i can still access. For original url i would a 404 error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is to add additional rule to handle your `test.php`. Here's an example of what you may end up with:

In .htaccess file in directory where you want to "server" your test.json:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^test.json$ /test.php [L,END]
```

In .htaccess file in the web root:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^test.php$ - [L,R=404]
```

Alternatively, if you want them all in the same directory, it could all be in one .htaccess file there:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^test.json$ /test.php [L,END]
RewriteRule ^test.php$ - [L,R=404]
```

Note that `END` flag is required to stop apache from doing another cycle and rewriting test.php to a 404 error.